# how to add multiple values ​and make the row repeat for the number of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of objects by each name and a dataframe like this.

Jimmy = ['chair','table','pencil']

Charles = ['smartphone','cake']

John = ['clock','paper']

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jimmy |
| 2 | Charles |
| 3 | John |

I would like to use a loop that allows me to obtain the following result.

| id | name | picks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jimmy | chair |
| 1 | Jimmy | table |
| 1 | Jimmy | pencil |
| 2 | Charles | smartphone |
| 2 | Charles | cake |
| 3 | John | clock |
| 3 | John | paper |

Answer (score 1):

You can `assign` and `explode`:

```
values = {'Jimmy': Jimmy, 'Charles': Charles, 'John': John}

out = df.assign(picks=df['name'].map(values)).explode('picks')
```

Or set up a DataFrame, `stack` and `merge`:

```
values = {'Jimmy': Jimmy, 'Charles': Charles, 'John': John}

out = df.merge(
         pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values, orient='index')
           .stack().droplevel(1).rename('picks'),
         left_on='name', right_index=True
        )
```

output:

```
   id     name       picks
0   1    Jimmy       chair
0   1    Jimmy       table
0   1    Jimmy      pencil
1   2  Charles  smartphone
1   2  Charles        cake
2   3     John       clock
2   3     John       paper
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make a dataframe relating names to picks, then join them together with merge:

```
import pandas as pd

#dataframe from question
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["id"] = [1, 2, 3]
df["name"] = ["Jimmy", "Charles", "John"]

#dataframe relating names to picks.
picks_df = pd.DataFrame()
picks_df["name"] = ["Jimmy", "Jimmy", "Jimmy", "Charles", "Charles", "John", "John"]
picks_df["picks"] = ["chair", "table", "pencil", "smartphone", "cake", "clock", "paper"]

#Merge and print
print(pd.merge(df, picks_df, on="name"))
```